# Vanilla Masonry - ie explorer issue

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

### http://jsfiddle.net/WH8tW/6/

I am having some issues with trying to get vanilla masonry to work with internet explorer (tested on ie 9)

the JavaScript i am using is

```
var container = document.getElementById('container');

var wall = new Masonry(container, {
    isFitWidth: true
});
container.style.display = "block";
wall.reload();
```

when testing in Chrome and Firefox it works amazing however in internet explorer the container's style doesn't even change (default `display:none;`), what is the cause of the issue and how can it be fixed

**reference to:** http://vanilla-masonry.desandro.com/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internet Explorer does not allow the embedding of external javascript files when served with the wrong mime type, and github served the script as a html file..

```
SEC7112: Script from https://raw.github.com/desandro/vanilla-masonry/master/masonry.min.js was blocked due to mime type mismatch
```

Instead you'll have to embed the external script into your fiddle to make it work in internet explorer, or if you're running your page on your own server you also have the choice of placing the script on your site and pointing it there:

http://jsfiddle.net/WH8tW/7/